# Firefox hangs waiting for ssl.google-analytics.com

Tags: proxy, firefox

It seems that FF has a problem with 403 Access Denied responses from proxies, at least for ssl.google-analytics.com.  I've found [this post](http://support.mozilla.com/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?comments_parentId=350798&forumId=1) which describes my problem.  I'm posting my workaround as an answer, but would also welcome any more information if anyone has it as I can't find anything!

**EDIT:** Note that the current version of Firefox which is experiencing this issue is 3.0.10

**EDIT:** Still there for FF 3.5...

Comment: Have you logged this as a bug? FF 3.0.10 is the current version that is being pushed by the auto updater in FireFox. If the developers are aware of this issue, esp as it appears to be a regression from 3.0.9 they should fix it quickly

Comment: I assumed from the post I found that someone did, but point taken.  I'll follow up to ensure that it is one filed.

Comment: I was also having this issue with a laptop at one of 2 work locations. This made me suspect Bilinear was right. Tried Open DNS at the location with the problem and that resolved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [Bug 492558](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=492558) that sounds like exactly what you are running into.  I'd recommend adding yourself to the CC list for the bug and clicking the "vote" link next to the priority.

Comment: +1 Thanks!  Saved me a few minutes of digging.

Answer (score 3):

My workaround was this:

1. Put an entry in your hosts file for ssl.google-analytics.com pointing to 127.0.0.1 file
2. Use a manual proxy settings in FF
3. Add ssl.google-analytics.com to the proxy exception list

This fails the connection to ssl.google-analytics.com and allows FF to proceed.

Comment: I was able to do steps (2) and (3) and get things working, trying to register a twitter account through tor.

Answer (score 2):

Simple work-around for now was to mark google-analytics.com as untrusted for the NoScript extension.  Credit to Brett Veenstra.

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble with the very same thing, and on several forums I saw people suggesting using addons to stop this from happening. But then I thought - why would it not just work, why isn't firefox fixing it? Now, I can't be 100% certain, but at least my issue was my ISP's DNS server, and I have a feeling everyone else having the issue is doing the same. I used Open DNS's DNS server (208.67.222.222 for preferred, 208.67.220.220 for alternate) and it fixed it right away, with no add-ons. I wonder if this could be a net-neutrality issue?

Comment: Not an option for us as we host our own dns.

Comment: You could add OpenDNS servers as 'forwarders' to your domain, so if your own DNS servers dont resolve it, the forwarders will.